# ¿Cómo borrar códigos del HTML en RMarkdown?

Tags: html, r, rstudio

Estoy usando `RMarkdown` y quiero borrar los códigos que salen en la imagen que está adjunto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con ECHO=F y con EVAL=F pero no los borra, sale error.

Este es el codigo que estoy usando.

```
{r echo=FALSE} 
library(xts) 
library(quantmod) 
prices <- getSymbols(params$symbol, auto.assign = FALSE) 
move <- Cl(last(prices)) - Op(last(prices))
```

Comment: Bienvenido @ArmandoDelgado a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Sería bueno que además de la imagen se incluya el código que lo genera y con ello reproducir el `html` respectivo en **RStudio** a través de su **knit** a efecto de orientarte mejor. Asimismo para que el código no aparezca en el markdown pero sí se ejecute, es `'''{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'} library(xts); x<-4; x '''` se mostrará la impresión de `x` es decir: `4` todo va entre tres comillas oblicuas (`) al inicio y al final pero acá tuve que usar comilla simple (') sino no se puede mostrar.

Comment: Este es el codigo que estoy usando.                                                   ```{r echo=FALSE}
library(xts)
library(quantmod)

prices <- getSymbols(params$symbol, auto.assign = FALSE)
move <- Cl(last(prices)) - Op(last(prices))

```

Answer (score 0):

Creo entender que el termino **"borrar"** se refiere a **no mostrar** de forma tácita el código de **R** en el documento **hmtl** que se genera a partir del **knit**.

En ese caso pueden haber varias variantes que conlleven a no mostrar el código R por diferentes motivos. De los cuales he podido identificar y son por lo general más comunes son los siguientes:

1. Colapsar el código completo sin resultados.
2. Mostrar el resultado (en formato **R**) pero no el código.
3. Mostrar sólo el resultado sin formato **R**.
4. Mostrar sólo el resultado en otra parte del texto (en formato **R**)
5. Mostrar código y resultado (en formato **R**).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al generarse el nuevo documento **R Markdown** para habilitar los botones (marcados en verde) que colapsan el código dentro del documento, se tiene que reemplazar esta linea:

```
---
title: "Web pages that use markdown"
output: html_document:
---
```

Por lo siguiente, con la respectiva [Indentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n) sino arrojará error:

```
---
title: "Web pages that use markdown"
output: 
    html_document:
        code_folding: hide
---
```

Asimismo los botones <kbd>Code</kbd> y <kbd>Hide</kbd> sólo estarán disponibles cuando no se ha empleado `echo=F o echo=FALSE`, por otro lado si los resultados van sin formato de **R** se emplea `results = 'asis'`.

Para terminar es posible emplear estilos **CSS** dentro de los `tag` de **HTML** correspondientes, para personalizar los textos o demás elementos decorativos del documento.

Por tanto, el código que genera la página mostrada arriba sería el siguiente:

````
---
title: "Web pages that use markdown"
output: 
    html_document:
        code_folding: hide
---

## Primera Parte

Para más detalles sobre R markdown ver <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

Cuando hagas click sobre el boton **Knit** en RStudio será generado un documento que tendrá embebido código de **R** en formato markdown o html:

```{r} 
#library(xts) 
#library(quantmod) 
#prices <- getSymbols(params$symbol, auto.assign = FALSE) 
#move <- Cl(last(prices)) - Op(last(prices)) 
```

## Segunda Parte
Mostrando el resultado (en formato **R**) pero no el código <span style="color:grey">( echo=F )</span>.

```{r echo=FALSE} 
set.seed(5)
a<-sample(1:10, 3)
a
```


## Tercera Parte
Mostrando solo el resultado sin formato **R** <span style="color:grey">( results = 'asis' )</span>.


```{r echo=F, results = 'asis'} 
a<-sample(1:20, 4)
a
```

## Cuarta Parte
>Mostrando solo el resultado en otra parte del texto (en formato **R**)

```{r echo=F, results = 'asis'} 
a<-sample(40:60, 6)
```

Aquí se muestra el valor de la variable <span style="color:#ff9933">"a"</span> con formato de salida **R**.

```{r echo=F} 
a
```

## Quinta Parte
Mostrando código y resultado (en formato **R**).
```{r} 
a<-matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
a
```
````

Comment: Para complementar tu respuesta ya que creo que la pregunta del AP apunta a suprimir los mensajes y warnings, podrías suprimir estos, configurando las opciones `message=FALSE, warning=FALSE` en cada chunk.

Comment: Es valido lo que indicas @PatricioMoracho, no lo incluí porque en teoría un documento de este tipo debe servir de respaldo o para documentar la investigación que se haya efectuado, por ende... los datos así como la lógica del código ya deberían estar pulidos en esta instancia a efecto de que forme parte del legajo que irá en un repositorio como github, RPubs, un blog, etc. No obstante cómo bien señalas pueden aparecer mensajes que no son deseables mostrarlos en la publicación final, pero considero que debería indicarse esto último al lector para que al reproducirlo, el lector este advertido.